# Как получить следующий и предыдущий пост опираясь на значение поле ACF?

Tags: wordpress

Обычное получение с помощью функций `get_previous_post()` и `get_next_post()` не достаточно. Пост типа `project` хранит в себе запароленный и архивные поля как указано на картинке:

[image]

Необходимо получить следующий\предыдущий пост, с условием, что это пост хранит в себе значение normal в поле `ACF`
Нашёл необходимые мне посты и безуспешно получается указать, чтобы следующий пост был из этого списка (наверное по дате лучше, чтобы не вело на оди и тот же пост).

```
public static function get_previous_normal_post( int $current_post_id = null ) {
    $current_post_id = ( $current_post_id === null ) ?? get_the_ID();
    $query = new WP_Query( [
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        'post_type'      => 'projects',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'meta_query'     => [
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'type'     => [
                'key'   => 'type',
                'value' => [ 'archive', 'commin_soon' ],
            ],
        ],
        'post__not_in'   => [ $current_post_id ],
    ] );
    wp_reset_postdata();
    $post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $query->posts, 'ID' );
    print_r(get_previous_post( false, implode( ',', $post_ids ) ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Похоже это то что нужно!](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139453/filter-next-post-link-and-previous-post-link-by-meta-key)

в `$next_posts` - можно запихнуть все ID'шники постов которые больше > `$current_post_id`

```
$_next_post = new WP_Query( [
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'post_type'      => 'projects',
  'post_status'    => 'publish',
  'meta_query'     => [
    'type' => [
      'key'       => 'type',
      'value' => [ 'archive', 'commin_soon' ],
    ],
  ],
  'post__not_in'   => $next_posts,
  'orderby' => 'ID',
  'order' => 'ASC',
] );
```

Правда у меня получилось два запроса, где в первом получем все с типом не нужным для исключения, а во втором получаю все с типом нужные и в `post__not_in` ставляю ответ с первого. После сверяюсь по `postID` на величину. Спасибо за помощь!